# MasterDetail Page Hamburger menu not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin, menu, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have code implemented in my project that shows the Hamburger menu, but for some reason i can only see the menu on slide (left to right), but cant see the hamburger (or any) icon.

Here is my MenuPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoginSystem.Views.MenuPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginSystem.Views">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu" >
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
                <Button Text="Calendar" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Command="{Binding Calendar_OnClicked}"/>
                <Button Text="My Profile" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Command="{Binding MyProfile_OnClicked}"/>
                <Button Text="Home" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Command="{Binding MyHome_OnClicked}"/>
                <Button Text="Logout" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Command="{Binding Logout_OnClicked}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <local:MyHomePage/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>


</MasterDetailPage>
```

And here is my MenuPage.cs:

```
using LoginSystem.Models;
using LoginSystem.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace LoginSystem.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MenuPage(string email, string password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            this.BindingContext = new Menu_vm(email, password);
        }

        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            this.BindingContext = new Menu_vm();
        }
    }
}
```

The page you see in the background in (Xaml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:LoginSystem.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginSystem.Views"    
             x:Class="LoginSystem.Views.MyHomePage"
             BackgroundColor="Azure" 
             Title="My Home Page">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Welcome}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Gold" FontSize="Large"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

.CS:

```
namespace LoginSystem.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyHomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyHomePage(string email, string password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            this.BindingContext = new MyHomePage_vm(email, password);
        }

        public MyHomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to remove NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);

Comment: I tried that, doesn't help much.

Comment: how you load MenuPage? Show the code please

Comment: await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(ret.Email, ret.Password));

Comment: That's your problem. Never add master-detail page into Navigation. Read more about Navigation patterns in Xamarin

Comment: I use that line of code in a viewmodel class called "LoginPage_vm.cs"

Comment: Oh, how would i go about to fix that? Sorry i am new to Xamarin

Comment: Read more about Navigation patterns in Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do that, do you have a quick fix to this?

Comment: There is no quick fix. This design is going against Xamarin (and mobile in general) design guidelines. You should either use ModalPush for master-detail (I personally never tried push modal) or substitute MainPage by it

Comment: When you say "substitute MainPage by it", i cant really do that as i require the user to be authenticated and to be in a different page for the menu to appear.

Comment: You asked the question and got an answer why it doesn't work. It is  up to you to figure out your app flow knowing what tools are available. I told you what tools you can use and what to read.

Comment: Just being straightforward, i did not get a proper answer. It's like saying "if you have any question, read the textbook". SO should be for those who can't "... figure out [their] app flow knowing what tools are available"

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a MasterDetail Page inside navigation page.

You can try the following changes :

1. Set your login page as the root for authenticating the user. Once the user is authenticated, set the root as your master detail page.
2. If you need further navigation from your detail page, wrap your detail page in a navigation page.

Read more about master detail pages and look at the samples provided - [Master-Detail Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check following

1. Update your detail section of MasterDetail page

> Blockquote

```
 <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:MyHomePage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

i.e. You need to wrap your "MyHomePage" with "NavigationPage" tag

2. In code file of MasterDetail page i.e MenuPage. Put following line in the constructor

   ```
       NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
       NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
   ```
3. In code file of MyHomePage. Remove the following code line in constructor

   ```
       NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
   ```

Comment: Update Detail Section with

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <local:MyHomePage/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

with 
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:MyHomePage/>
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>